# Getting Exception "Incorrect syntax near 'System'" while using SqlCommandBuilder

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I am learning `SqlCommandbuilder`, but when I try to implement it, I am getting an exception. This is my code.

**Code snippet #1**: working fine

```
protected void btnGetStudent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tblStudents where ID = @Id", con);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", txtStudentID.Text);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Students"); // now this FILL is very useful as it manages opening of the connection and then executing the command to get the data and the loading it into the dataset and then closes the connection.

    ViewState["SQL_Query"] = da.SelectCommand.ToString();
    ViewState["Data"] = ds;

    if (ds.Tables["Students"].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        DataRow dr = ds.Tables["Students"].Rows[0];
        txtStudentID.Text = dr["Id"].ToString();
    }    
}
```

**Code snippet #2**: causes an exception:

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

    dataAdapter.SelectCommand =
        new SqlCommand((string)ViewState["SQL_Query"], con);
    SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

    DataSet ds = (DataSet)ViewState["Data"];
    DataRow dr = ds.Tables["Students"].Rows[0];
    dr["Id"] = txtStudentID.Text;

    int rowsUpdated = dataAdapter.Update(ds, "Students"); // Exception
}
```

Exception:

> Incorrect syntax near 'System'

[image]

[image]

Comment: Negative voter please put a comment too so that I can fix my question. You have full right to give negative vote but do take some time out to explain negative vote.

Comment: Since I am a beginner I don't know what other details are required, If you ask me I will put my entire project solution here.

Comment: Wondering: what's the point of instantiating that `builder`? I don't see you using it

Comment: I am just following this tutorial "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F811ruWEHjY&index=13&list=PL6n9fhu94yhX5dzHunAI2t4kE0kOuv4D7"

Comment: In the working version you pass `"Select * from tblStudents where ID = @Id"` to the DataAdapter, in the broken case you pass `(string)ViewState["SQL_Query"]`. What's the value of `(string)ViewState["SQL_Query"]`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: See  my edit. thanks. Check the immediate window content.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Can you put a small code snippet on how can I use command builder in my case and guide me why I am getting exception.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not the best at working directly with ADO.NET. I can, however, link you to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) where the code they use isn't exactly the same (look at the methods calling order)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167038/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-camilo-terevinto).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out why: The videos you are following use .NET 2.0. How do I know?

Look at the documentation for the [SqlCommandBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder(v=vs.80).aspx) class:

- Example for .NET 2.0:

  ```
  DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
  adapter.Fill(dataSet, tableName);

  //code to modify data in DataSet here

  //Without the SqlCommandBuilder this line would fail
  adapter.Update(dataSet, tableName);
  ```
- Example for .NET 3.0+:

  ```
  DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
  adapter.Fill(dataSet, tableName);

  //code to modify data in DataSet here

  builder.GetUpdateCommand();

  //Without the SqlCommandBuilder this line would fail
  adapter.Update(dataSet, tableName);
  ```

The obvious difference between them is the call to `builder.GetUpdateCommand();` before calling `adapter.Update`, so you are missing that.

That said: I'd suggest you to switch to some tutorial that *at least* uses .NET 4.5